# Drift kinetic equation orderings

Tags: plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, non-equilibrium

I'm trying to derive the first order drift kinetic equation given in the book [Collisional Transport in Magnetized Plasmas](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Collisional_Transport_in_Magnetized_Plas.html?id=nm-V01E0H2MC&redir_esc=y) by P. Helander and D. T. Sigmar, section **6.5**.

I understand that the procedure is:

1. Consider the kinetic equation in some phase-space variables.
2. Using the orderings of each term obtain the first order kinetic equation.
3. Finally, take the average of the equation over the gyroangle.

The equation is in the variables $(\boldsymbol{R},\mathscr{E},\mu,\vartheta)$. $\boldsymbol{R}$ is the guiding center position, $\mathscr{E}=mv^2/2 +Ze\Phi$ the energy, $\mu$ the magnetic moment, and $\vartheta$ the gyroangle. The kinetic equation in this case is

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\dot{\boldsymbol{R}}\cdot\nabla f+\dot{\mathscr{E}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathscr{E}}+\dot{\mu}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu}+\dot{\vartheta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vartheta}=C(f)$$

where $f$ is the particle distribution function and $C$ some collision operator.

My problem comes when considering the orderings of each term. I understand that the phenomena is diffusive so $\partial/\partial t\sim\delta^2\nu$, then the first term is second order in the collision frequency $\nu$. The collision operator must be of order $\nu$. Because the magnetic moment is an adiabatic invariant $\dot{\mu}=0$. Also, the time variation of the gyroangle should be of order the gyrofrequency $\dot{\vartheta}\sim\Omega$.

**I don't know how to see the orders of the second and third terms**, and why in this case the energy $\mathscr{E}$ is not conserved. The resulting drift kinetic equation is

$$\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial t}+\langle{\dot{\mathscr{E}}}\rangle \frac{\partial f_0}{\partial\mathscr{E}}+\dot{\boldsymbol{R}}\cdot\nabla f_0=\langle C(f_0)\rangle$$

where $f_0=f_0(\boldsymbol{R},\mathscr{E},\mu,t)$ is the averaged distribution function and $\langle\quad\rangle$ is an average over the gyroangle.

Comment: Why do some, but not all, terms seem to have undergone an ensemble average?

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the $f$ was actually $f_0$. It seems to me that they really don't use any ordering, just average over the gyroangle and $\dot{\mu}=0$. But still they mention the ordering of some terms...

Comment: I asked about the ensemble average because that is why those terms disappeared.  In most of these types of approaches, there are assumptions about the constancy of terms for various processes.  In the case of drift kinetics and gyrokinetic theory, one assumes different things are constant over a gyroperiod (e.g., I think the latter only cares about the guiding center motion of the particles and ignores their gyro orbits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to start by saying that I really appreciate this question. I have struggled to find a clear explanation of the ordering used to derive "The Drift-Kinetic Equation". I too tried to work through 6.5 in Helander and Sigmar but was disappointed by their hasty explanation of the ordering.

In the business of “ordering” it’s hard to be very rigorous unless you know *exactly* what to do (and I do not). So with that caveat, here is my admittedly **very** heuristic answer to your question:

For completeness this is the starting point,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\dot{\mathbf{R}}\cdot\nabla f+\dot{\mathscr{E}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathscr{E}}+\dot{\mu}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu}+\dot{\vartheta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vartheta}=C(f)\tag{1}$$

#### Energy Term

The third term on the LHS of eq. (1) (term proportional to $\dot{\mathscr{E}}$) can be ordered using the assumption that time-variations of quantities are driven by diffusive processes. This amounts to substituting:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \rightarrow \nu\delta^2$$

(see eq. 8.2 in H&S and the surrounding text.)

One might also be able to justify this ordering using equipartition of energy to relate energy to temperature ($T$) by writing $\mathscr{E} \sim T$.

Then, using material from Chapter 1 of Helander and Sigmar (H&S),

$$\mathbf{q} = -\kappa\nabla T \hskip{1cm}\text{with}\hskip{1cm} \kappa \propto \nu_{ii}\rho_i^2$$

and from Eq. 2.17 in H&S,

$$\frac{dT}{dt} \propto -\nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{d\mathscr{E}}{dt} \sim \frac{dT}{dt} \sim \nabla \cdot(\nu\rho^2\nabla T) \sim \nu\rho^2/L^2 = \nu\delta^2.$$

This is what H&S essentially claims. I will admit, this is not exactly correct since I simply replace the gradient with $1/L$ instead of finding a factor of $1/L_B = |\nabla \ln B|$ as per H&S's definition of $\delta = \rho/L_B$. But H&S is actually inconsistent in its use of $L$ vs. $L_B$ (see for example Ch. 8) so I believe they are interchangeable.

#### Drift Term

To order the "drift term" in eq. (1), i.e. $\dot{\mathbf{R}}\cdot \nabla f$. I think we need an additional piece of information which is not given to the reader explicitly. I believe we are meant to take the guiding center velocity as approximately equal to the thermal speed, $\dot{\mathbf{R}} \sim v_T$.

I *do* expect this to hold in the parallel direction given the approximation: $\dot{\mathbf{R}}_\parallel \approx v_\parallel$ which *is* given to the reader, but I do *not* expect this to be true in the perpendicular direction. In fact, the g.c. velocity in the perpendicular direction we have an additional factor of $\delta$ as per the "transport ordering" discussed in H&S Ch. 8 i.e. that macro-flows are suppressed by a factor of $\delta$ when compared to the thermal speed, $V \sim \delta v_T.$

With all this, the desired ordering follows quickly,

$$\dot{\mathbf{R}}\cdot \nabla f \sim v_T L^{-1}f \sim  \Omega(\rho_s/L)f \sim \Omega \delta f$$

where I have introduced the "sound gyro-radius": $\rho_s = v_T/\Omega$ and extended the definition of $\delta$ s.t. $\delta = \rho_s/L$.

We then recover the ordering claimed by H&S, i.e. that the drift term is an order of $\delta$ smaller than the $\partial f/\partial \vartheta$ term.

#### Conclusion

My genuine hope is that someone comes along and provides a more rigorous answer to this question. But this is what I can offer at this juncture.

Regarding the apparent energy non-conservation: I recommend you take a look at Section 5 of this famous paper:  [Baños A., Jr. (1967) Plasma Phys. 1, 305.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0022377800003317). Essentially, this guiding-centre framework is an approximation, and non-constant, externally-modulated fields are doing work on the particle hence the gain in energy.

Also, you should be careful with your final statement that $f_0$ is the "averaged" distribution function. I read this part of H&S as saying that once you order eq. (1), you look at terms of order $\mathcal{O}(\delta^0, \Delta^0)$ and you find that the largest term is simply,

$$\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \vartheta} = 0$$

implying - to this order - $f_0$ is **independent** of the gyrophase $\vartheta$. To solve for $f_0$ one must advance to the next order and retain the other terms in eq. (1), which is subsequently gyro-averaged to make the whole equation independent of $\vartheta$.

Comment: I've moved from plasma physics a while ago, so I find a bit difficult right now to review this. Anyhow I mark this as accepted as I think it is a pretty detailed answer. Hope future students might find this post useful.